# FileNoFoundException when trying to backup Database to SD card

Tags: android

I am trying to backup my databases from my app to my sd card but every time I try I get  `FileNotFoundException` and I am not sure why when the name of the database is right

code to backup databases

```
try{
        File dbFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/my.app.package/databases/Games.db");
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/BCAData");
           if (!exportDir.exists()) {
              exportDir.mkdirs();
           }
           File file = new File(exportDir, dbFile.getName());

           file.createNewFile();
           FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(dbFile).getChannel();  //fails here
           FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
           try {
              inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
           } finally {
              if (inChannel != null)
                 inChannel.close();
              if (outChannel != null)
                 outChannel.close();
           }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in my content provider I have the database name like this

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Games";
private static final String GAMES_TABLE = "Games";
```

error:

```
12-14 19:38:38.313: W/System.err(10452): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.tyczj.bowling/databases/Games.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-14 19:38:38.313: W/System.err(10452):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
12-14 19:38:38.313: W/System.err(10452):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
12-14 19:38:38.323: W/System.err(10452):    at com.tyczj.bowling.services.DatabaseExportService.onHandleIntent(DatabaseExportService.java:27)
12-14 19:38:38.323: W/System.err(10452):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
12-14 19:38:38.333: W/System.err(10452):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 19:38:38.333: W/System.err(10452):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 19:38:38.343: W/System.err(10452):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
12-14 19:38:38.343: W/System.err(10452): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-14 19:38:38.353: W/System.err(10452):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-14 19:38:38.353: W/System.err(10452):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
12-14 19:38:38.353: W/System.err(10452):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
12-14 19:38:38.353: W/System.err(10452):    ... 6 more
```

I dont see why this is wrong that is the path so is that not the name of the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
File dbFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/my.app.package/databases/Games.db");
```

Try:

```
File dbFile = getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Comment: You beat me by four seconds, but take a closer look at `DATABASE_NAME` there is no `".db"`.

Comment: @Sam: Ah, good point. I have adjusted my answer to match. To the OP: there is no automatic file extension added to databases, so whatever you are using as the name with `SQLiteOpenHelper` or `SQLiteDatabase` is the filename. You still should use `getDatabasePath()`, though, to get your `File` object.

Comment: ahh I see i thought it needed the `.db` since it was a database file, got rid of that and it worked great thanks!